# PDO - Change the display format of dates and time according to the user country

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

We have created a website for France, but we will open it to foreign users (American, German, Chinese, etc.)

The problem is that all the dates saved in the database are recorded in the French zone (`'Europe/Paris'` in my php.ini file, `'datetime'` fields in mysql)

**And all of the site's queries simply retrieve dates and display them**

I am using PDO:

```
<?php
try {
  $engine = 'mysql';
  $host = 'loclahost;
  $port = '3310';
  $database = 'mydb';
  $user_bdd = 'myuser';
  $password = 'mypwd';
  $dns = $engine.':port='.$port.';dbname='.$database.";host=".$host;
  $bdd = new PDO($dns, $user_bdd, $password);
  $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (Exeption $erreur) {
  die ('Erreur : '.$erreur->getMessage());
}
?>
```

An example of a request:

```
$request = $bdd->prepare('SELECT date from invoices WHERE id = 1');
$request->execute();
$result = $request->fetch();
```

Result :

```
array (size=1)
  'date' => string '2017-09-22 13:57:09'
```

In my HTML :

```
<div><?= result['date'] ?></div>
```

**How to change the date and time according to the user?
Is there a way to do this directly by modifying the PDO connection?**

Knowing that in the database I assign for each user a code for the country

```
FR = French
US = American
CZ = Chinese
```

Example for an American user, the same query will give:

```
array (size=1)
  'date' => string '2017-09-22 04:57:09'
```

Comment: This is not the problem of the database. The database should ideally store the time in UTC but that also depends on your design and requirements. The time should be displayed to the user based on their locale which means you need to perform that client side or in the UI layer. This has nothing to do with PDO

Comment: Also country code can't help you with the timezone. Many countries use multiple timezones.

Comment: And very important: Do not catch PDO exceptions if you have no intention of recovering. Do not display error messages directly to the user. You need to remove that try-catch

Comment: @Dharman Thank you for the try-catch, I will remove that. So, how must I do to change this display ?

Comment: Either ask the user for the preferred timezone and store that personalization in the database or use their browser settings and JavaScript to convert the UTC time to their local time. These are only suggestions. You need to research this broad topic yourself. This is also a very good article I recommend you read in full https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

Answer (score 0):

If the time zone of the user is known, you can convert the time to another time zone with DateTime.

```
$dtLosAngeles = date_create('2017-09-22 13:57:09',new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'))
  ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'))
;
echo $dtLosAngeles->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2017-09-22 04:57:09
```

America / New_York delivers a different time!
As said, none of this has anything to do with PDO.